# SQL syntax, cant update table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the error

> Could not update users table: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long = '-2.8867589' WHERE Username = 'test1'' at line 1"

when i run this sql statement:

```
if($updateuser=mysql_query("UPDATE Users SET Long = '$long' WHERE Username = '$_SESSION[myusername]'")){
    echo 'Users table updated';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`LONG` is a reserved word in MySQL (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)).  It is a bad name for a column, but if you use it, then you need backticks:

```
UPDATE Users
    SET `Long` = '$long'
    WHERE Username = '$_SESSION[myusername]';
```

You should also switch to mysqli and use parameterized queries.